# How to autorefresh a webpage that does not trigger the on-close alert while auto-refreshing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

So, to auto-refresh my webpage, I'm currently using in my header:

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
```

and this interferes with the

```
<script> window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;</script>
```

event.

is there a way to make the two "compatible" ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, [W3C recommends against auto-refreshing](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh).

That said, you might try [reloading the page with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload). You could stop listening to the unload event right before programmatically reloading the page and then re-listen afterwards.